# Filtering dates based on condition

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with the following structure : Filed names ID C_Time Groups SYSTEM Group1

[image]

I would like to display those cases that have the status as CLOSE (Groups) in  level2,  that were Created (Group1) in level1 after C_Time is>= 1/15/2020.

So in the above case (sample attached as link) only the ID 2 should be displayed since ID1 was Created in level1  before 1/15/2020
I am trying to use the following syntax -

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN TM1.SYSTEM = 'level1' and TM1.Group1 = 'Created'
     and TM1.C_Time >= '2019-11-01 00:00:00' THEN TM1.ID  END)  as CDF  
FROM TABLE AS TM1 
Where TM1.SYSTEM IN ('level2') AND TM1.Groups = 'CLOSE'
```

However, I am not getting the desired results. Any advise would be helpful.

Thank you all

Regards,
Rishi

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can group by id and set the conditions in the having clause:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having max(case when group1 = 'Status' and system = 'level2' then groups end) = 'CLOSE'
   and max(case when group1 = 'Created' and system = 'level1' then c_time end) >= '2020-01-15 00:00:00'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7DhpoKSxyCag224wfFJBKV/0) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).
Result:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 2   |
```

Comment: Hi Forpas,  Thank you for your informed answer.  However,  I am not getting any values in my original query the I use the having clause.  Will try to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as:

```
select id
from t
where (group1 = 'Status' and system = 'level2') or
      (group1 = 'Created' and system = 'level1' and ctime > '2020-01-15')
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

The above assumes that you don't have duplicate rows.  If you do, change the `having` to:

```
having count(distinct group1) = 2
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,  Thank you for your reply. However, I am getting the cases that are closed in level1 also and some of the level2 ones are missing.  Will look into it again.

Comment: @user10813058 . . . This works for the data you have provided in the question.  It is unclear why it would not be working.